# Get the absolute position of a caret in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find out how to get the absolute position (top px, left px) of a caret in a contenteditable div. So far the only answer I've been able to find was how to get the index position. However the index position isn't very helpful as the only way to calculate the absolute position of the caret would be to use the width and height of the letters. But this wouldn't work because the size of the window and contenteditable div change. Is it possible to find the absolute position of the caret, if so how would it be done?

Comment: Can you add the code that you reached, and I will modify it so that we get the values of the sides instead of the center?

Comment: What do you mean by this?